# Towers of coins puzzle

Tags: puzzle, integer-partitions

Let $n$ be a natural number.

You are given $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ coins which are arranged in towers. Every turn you pick up the top coin of each tower and gather all these into a new tower. Prove that eventually (after finitely many turns) you get towers of the following heights: $\{{ 1,2,3,\dots,n }\}$.

For example: for $n = 6$ (number of coins $21$): and for the initial state of towers: $\{{17, 2, 1, 1}\}$

- Inital state: $\{{17, 2, 1, 1}\}$
- Turn 1: $\{{16, 1, 4}\}$
- Turn 2: $\{{15, 3, 3}\}$
- Turn 3: $\{{14, 2, 2, 3}\}$
- Turn 4: $\{{13, 1, 1, 2, 4}\}$
- Turn 5: $\{{12, 1, 3, 5}\}$
- Turn 6: $\{{11, 2, 4, 4}\}$
- Turn 7: $\{{10, 1, 3, 3, 4}\}$
- Turn 8: $\{{9, 2, 2, 3, 5}\}$
- Turn 9: $\{{8, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5}\}$
- Turn 10: $\{{7, 1, 3, 4, 6}\}$
- Turn 11: $\{{6, 2, 3, 5, 5}\}$
- Turn 12: $\{{5, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5}\}$
- Turn 13: $\{{4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 6}\}$
- Turn 14: $\{{3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6}\}$
- Turn 15: $\{{2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6}\}$
- Turn 16: $\{{1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7}\}$
- Turn 17: $\{{2, 3, 4, 6, 6}\}$
- Turn 18: $\{{1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5}\}$
- Turn 19: $\{{1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6}\}$
- Turn 20: $\{{1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6}\}$
- Turn 21: $\{{2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6}\}$
- Turn 22: $\{{1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}\}$
- Turn 23: $\{{2, 3, 4, 5, 7}\}$
- Turn 24: $\{{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5}\}$

Comment: This procedure has a name: "Bulgarian Solitaire", if anyone is interested in googling for results.

Comment: The question was also re-asked more recently, but I can't find that version.

Comment: This paper discusses the problem https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00885.pdf

Comment: A 1985 paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323643)

Comment: How many turns do we need in the worst case scenario ?

Comment: @Peter, $n^2-n$, according to [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_solitaire)